# Using xampp on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on Ubuntu and trying to run a project developed on Windows on Ubuntu. I am getting 404 page not found permission. I guess it is due to permissions and ownership but I can't figure it out. Suggest how to get it working. Folder `citymagic` has permission `755` and has root as its owner and group.

[image: Contents of citymagic]

Comment: As far as I remember the **`xampp`** runs also an apache2. Here the user and group is normally `www-data`. If that's right you can set it with `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./`

Comment: I have tried that too.When I try to run localhost, I get default dashboard of xampp. Dashboard in htdocs also have same permission and ownership as my project.

Comment: Is the dashboard using php-files? Is php5 activated? Create a simple html-file and check if you can open it. Maybe you have some settings in the `.htaccess` file. Check `ls -lah` to show also the hidden files...